# What's the danger of not encoding brackets in URL?

Tags: url, rfc3986

I have read this question: [Is it ok to have brackets in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13225028/759866) and the related [RFC 3986](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html).

Answers to this question say that `[` and `]` are classified as *gen-delims* by the RFC and should therefore be encoded, but *do not explain how failing to do so would be problematic*.

So, I fail to understand what can be the problem with a URL such as:

```
http://example.com/?foo[bar]=baz
```

It is obvious why `&` should be encoded for example, as it is used as a separator between query parameters.

But **what is the use of `[` and `]` in a URL** that would make their intent confusing if they were not URL-encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [RFC 3986 section 3.2.2](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#sec-3.2.2):

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6 [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal within square brackets ("[" and "]").

For example, the IPv4 address for you local machine is 127.0.0.1, so you can access it with the url

```
http://127.0.0.1/
```

The IPv6 equivalent is `::1`, so the url would be

```
http://[::1]/
```

Comment: I've seen this line, but am not sure to understand it. Could you please give an example?

Comment: That answers my question then, thanks. It's unfortunate that the RFC forces square brackets to be encoded in URL parameters, even though they seemingly can only be used in the host part.