# Encoding all the special characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have to encode the string that I receive here and pass it as a URL parameter so I don't believe I can pass either / or a paranthesis ( so considering I have the following string

```
KEY WEST / Florida(FL)
```

I am trying the following

```
encodeURIComponent("KEY WEST / Florida(FL)")
"KEY%20WEST%20%2F%20Florida(FL)"

escape("KEY WEST / Florida(FL)")
"KEY%20WEST%20/%20Florida%28FL%29"
```

Neither of them are encoding the string which I can decode later in my code as the first one is keeping the () and the second one is keeping the /

How do I do this in one shot and at a later time decode it when needed?

Also it seems like escape() has been deprecated so which way to do the encoding is preferred?

Comment: Where are you needing to decode it?  The `encodeURIComponent` should put it in the format that backend servers should have pre-existing logic to know how to decode them.

Comment: If `encodeURIComponent` leaves the `( )` alone, you can be confident that the characters do not need to be encoded; that's the whole point.

Comment: It's not working for my application. The encoded string is not being recognized by my Angular router. If I enter a plain text like just Key West, it works fine though.

Comment: Just added a little more detail on how it's breaking my AngularJS router when I try to pass the param using encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For URL encoding, `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` functions should be used.

`encodeURI` encodes only special characters, while `encodeURIComponent` also encodes characters that have a meaning in the URL, so it is used to encode query strings, for example.

Parentheses are (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13227416/8376184)), however, allowed anywhere in the URL without encoding them, that's why `encodeURIComponent` leaves them as-is.

The `escape` function [*can be considered* deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape), and although it officially isn't, it should be avoided.

---

> so which way to do the encoding is preferred?

- For entire URLs, [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)
- For URL parts, e.g. query string of fragment, [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Also see [When are you supposed to use escape instead of `encodeURI` / `encodeURIComponent`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75980/8376184)

Comment: So when I try to use either and pass it into my router, it's breaking the AngularJS routing and throwing a 404. I am passing it as param

Comment: .when('/myedpoint/:param?', {
                templateUrl: 'components/test/testPage.html',
                controller: 'TestPageController'
            })

Comment: Accepting this answer as this is technically what I had asked for initially and this is a very accurate and elaborate answer but I created another ticket if you have the interest to take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797981/angularjs-url-parameter-returning-a-404-upon-encoding