# AngularJS URL parameter returning a 404 upon encoding

Tags: angularjs, encoding, utf-8, escaping, encodeuricomponent

I am trying to pass a string as a url parameter, specifically as param1 in my URL. Here is the router code in my AngularJS code

```
.when('/test/:param1?/:param2?', {
    templateUrl: 'components/test/testPage.html',
    controller: 'TestPageController'
 })
```

I am looking to pass the following string to the testPage.html page

```
KEY WEST / Florida(FL)
```

I have tried several kinds of encodings as suggested in my previous question here

[Encoding all the special characters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777478/encoding-all-the-special-characters-in-javascript)

```
param1 = encodeURIComponent("KEY WEST / Florida(FL)")
"KEY%20WEST%20%2F%20Florida(FL)"

param1 = escape("KEY WEST / Florida(FL)")
"KEY%20WEST%20/%20Florida%28FL%29"
```

But no matter what I do, I get a HTTP 404 Page not Found. I understand that the second approach may not work because the escaped string also has a / in it so maybe I should use the first approach but even that doesn't work. Is there a limit on the number of characters on the URL parameter that I am not aware of?

Comment: have you tried to escape reserved characters like this?  

encodeURIComponent("KEY WEST \\/ Florida(FL)")
"KEY%20WEST%20%5C%2F%20Florida(FL)"

Comment: Yes and that did not work.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren’t using query strings for this?

Comment: The strings are not big enough to be using a post so just using GETs with query strings.